# gridheight doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to use the GridBagLayout, but I've some trouble with it. I want to make a layout using 12 rows. So first I make two JPanels filling up the first two rows (with gridheight = 1). Then I make 5 other JPanels to fill up the other 10 rows (with gridheight = 2). The bottom 5 JPanels get gridheight = {2,4,6,8,10}, so they won't overlap or anything. 
The problem I get now is this:
**All the JPanels get the same size!**

I also fill up BOTH ways and not using any anchors. If I add a JPanel with gridx = 1, gridy = 0 and gridheight = 2, then it will have a doubled height, so what's the deal here? Do I have to tell the layout system the total amount of rows I am going to use beforehand? If so how do I do that?

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the first two rows I say:

```
 c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
 c.gridwidth = 1;
 c.gridheight = 1;
 c.ipadx = 100;
 c.ipady = h / (2 * columns + 2);
 c.weightx = 1.0;
 c.weighty = 1.0;
```

And for the next rows I only change c.ipady:

```
 c.ipady = h / (columns + 1);
```

So this basically solved my problem, but I still think it could have been a lot easier.

P.S. The variable h is the hight of my screen.

Comment: This is really not the right idea because now you are just trying to use GridBagLayout like absolute layout.

Answer (score 2):

there are several aspects to GridBagLayout (GBL) that get missed by first time users.

1) components placed inside the GBL will initialize at their "preferred" size.  JPanel, iirc, has a preferred size of 1x1.

2) if you want the GBL cells to resize according to the enclosing container, you need to give them a weightx and weighty.  what those two attributes do is say, give the cell a percentage of the available area according to the ratio of all the weightx's and weighty's assigned.  e.g. if i have 2 cells and 1 has weightx = 1.0 and the second one is given 2.0, then the first cell will be 1/2 as wide as the second (or the second one will be twice as wide).

3) GBL takes alot of trial and error when you first dive in, BUT it is the most powerful, flexible, and reliable layout (especially compared to nested layouts, blech)

Comment: +1, but the last point, point 3) is debatable. Some swear by 3rd party layouts such as MigLayout.

Comment: Hmm, in two minds...compound layouts make much easier to generate highly complex layouts, which are manageable, easier to update and maintain (IMHO) - When the only tool you have is a hammer, then every problem looks like a nail. Limiting yourself to a single layout is, well, limiting.  I'd say MigLayout is more flexible and feature rich, but adds a external dependency...it all comes down to needs

Comment: no one said it's the only solution.  my feeling on third party solutions, though is, if the jdk already supplies what you need, why leverage something else.  i try to only leverage to fill holes the jdk does not provide.

Comment: I have used weighty in a various amount of ways, but I don't get any different results. So how should I proceed?

Comment: did you specify fill for the GridBagContraints when binding each element?  fill = NONE will cause them all to collapse to preferred/minimum sizes.

Comment: i recommend perusing this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html - it's a good place to start

Comment: I've already seen that page, but for some reason the results seem to be different to the expectations created by this page.

Comment: I also figured out a solution which I'll place right now!